# Flask-WTF field choices with "&nbsp;"

Tags: flask-wtforms

I'd like to add indent to the `choices` of WTForm field(SelectField).

```
Root Category/
    Sub Category1/
    Sub Category2/
```

As listed below, I want to add 3 spaces before `Sub Category1`.

WTForm is built dynamically by query.

view.py

```
form.parent.choices = [(0, gettext('Root Category'))]
form.parent.choices.extend(categories)
```

Each select option is built as follows:

```
tree.append((child.id, '   ' * level + child.name))
```

If I put `'   '`, it is ignored. (Bootstrap CSS is used.)

If I put `'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'`, it is autoescaped, so it is printed to select option.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Unicode code for [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) character, this should help you:

```py
tree.append((child.id, '\xa0' * level + child.name))
```